# Changing the scale/span of y axis in a time domain plot

Tags: graphing-functions

I have a set of `x,y` pairs, where `x` is always the *time*, and `y` can be anything, with any set of values.

Due to user interface/graphic constrains the x axis is *longer* (in pixels) than the y axis, hence x values span on 400px and in y axis values span over 250px ( or similar)

But still I need to plot the graph as "honest" as I can.

Is it acceptable if I draw the y values over a shorter length ( vertical pixels) ?
That means that my visual slop will changed dramatically for `f(x)=y`.

How would you plot a time domain curve when the y axis is shorter than x ?